# Diamond inheritance with templated base class: Base<Derived>

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, diamond-problem

I have diamond problem when inheriting from templated base class which takes Derived class as template argument.

Normaly this problem is solvable with virtual inheritance like this:

```
class Base0
{
protected:
    int var = 0;
};

class Base1 : public virtual Base0
{
};

class Base2 : public virtual Base0
{

};

class Derived :
    public Base1,
    public Base2
{
public:
    void f()
    {
        var = 1; // OK single var
    }
};
```

However I have this scenario:

```
template<typename DERIVED_CLASS>
class TemplatedBase0
{
protected:
    int var = 0;
};

class Base1 : public virtual TemplatedBase0<Base1>
{
};

class Base2 : public virtual TemplatedBase0<Base2>
{

};

class Derived :
    public Base1,
    public Base2
{
public:
    void f()
    {
        var = 1; // ERROR: var is ambigous
    }
};
```

I understand that in above case templated base class is not the same, ie. there are 2 completely unrealted base classes involved and it looks like virtual inheritance dosnt work.

So my question is, is there any way to make this work? what design/approach should I take here?

I need to have base class as a template which takes derived class type. but how to make diamond inheritance possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want to only have a single `int var;` in `Derived`, you need to move it to a non-template base class:

```
class GenericTemplatedBase0
{
  protected:
    int var = 0;
};

template<typename DERIVED_CLASS>
class TemplatedBase0 : virtual public GenericTemplatedBase0
{
    // ...
};

class Base1 : public TemplatedBase0<Base1>
{
};

class Base2 : public TemplatedBase0<Base2>
{
};

class Derived : public Base1, public Base2
{
  public:
    void f()
    {
        var = 1;
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need and want, thanks friend!

Answer (score 1):

There is no diamond in your code. Your `Derived` has two different `var`s. Depending on which you want you write:

```
Base1::var = 1;
Base2::var = 1;
```

> but how to make diamond inheritance possible?

It is not clear why you want a diamond. If your aim is to have only a single `var` in `Derived` you need a different design.